# How to install Ubuntu without a CD or USB from Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, unetbootin, easybcd

NOTE: This is my first post, it won't let me post images or more than 2 links, so I'll add all the links here:

I got a new laptop which has Windows 10 on it, the weird thing about this laptop is it has no CD drive. I also have no USB key. I decided to give Windows 10 a chance, but I've been experiencing not stop problems and bullshit with it, as a developer, everything with Windows is just so awkward and backwards, I can't take it any longer. So I need to install Ubuntu without a CD or USB key. I shrank the Windows partition by about 50%, so theres plenty of unformatted space there.

I first tried the program called UNetBootin, I'm not fully sure how it works, but edits the MBR and adds a new boot option to it, and its supposed to let you install Ubuntu from a .iso file located in your C:/. Heres how I set it up:
[image 1]

When I reboot, a bootloader comes up and I get two options Windows 10 or UNetBootin. When I go into UNetbootin, heres what happens:
[image 2]

So it looks like the UNetBootin tool isn't getting loaded at all, the boot manager is just looking for a Windows installation.

I tried a second program called EasyBCD, but when I start it up, heres the message it gives me:
[image 3]
So its telling me my laptop is booting up in EFI mode and that might be a problem. I tried going into BIOS and I enabled this legacy option which sounded like it meant the boot method (switching to the boot method that older versions of Windows use), but EasyBCD is still giving me this message.

Its a pretty good program, got lots of features, and gives you info about the MBR:

There are a total of 2 entries listed in the bootloader.

```
Default: Windows 10
Timeout: 30 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: D:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 10
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi

Entry #2
Name: UNetbootin
BCD ID: {0ee116e8-6a72-11e6-b91a-e09467f2147f}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \ubnldr.mbr
```

The problem is that when I wanna add a third option, if I select the Linux tab, all the fields are blanked out:
[image 4]
I don't know if this is because of that EFI issue or what.

I heard of another program called WUBI, but I have a feeling it wont work. Is there another way to do this? If I formatted the second partition to Ext3, and then mounted that partition to Windows (if thats possible), would it be possible to extract the files from the ISO file into the partition somehow? Then I'd just need to install GRUB in the MBR.

Or maybe if I make a 3rd small partition, format it as FAT32 or something, which has no OS installed on it, maybe I can add the Ubuntu.iso file there, and use Unetbootin.

I've run out of ideas on how to do get Ubuntu installed on this second partition.

Comment: That thread did not feature any solutions to the problem.

Comment: Do you have a UTP port ? [This is how a UTP cable and interface in a laptop looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Eze.jpg) I found [**this**](https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/10/08/how-to-install-ubuntu-locally-over-the-network/) article on the internet, maybe you can find more information there.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that UTP cable method. I don't have the cable unfortunately.

Comment: @bithons that blog is from 2007. Is UTP even around anymore?

Comment: A [community supported Wubi version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki) has solved the UEFI boot issues. see [wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info).  [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) instead of EasyBCD could be also better for your problem. [REFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind) as boot manger, too.  It is no complete solution, but all programs can be helpful to create your own solution.

Comment: @SelfDecodeSupport: Nonetheless it provides the answer to your question too: that it's not really possible.

Comment: @MarkKirby I was not able to make a comment, to ask if he had UTP connection. I do not want to write full 'encyclopedia' before I know the answer, so that is why I made it so short.

Comment: @SelfDecodeSupport Yes UTP is still around, that is why I ask the question right?